# How can I get the name of the selected IME in C#?

Tags: c#, ime

I'd like to get the current input method from C#, eg. weather I'm using "US keyboard", "United Kingdom keyboard", "Microsoft Pinyin", "Microsoft Wubi" or "Sogou Pinyin" ("搜狗拼音输入法").

How would this be possible? Currently I'm only able to get the input language using `InputLanguageManager.Current.CurrentInputLanguage.Name`

Comment: maybe this will help https://yal.cc/csharp-get-current-keyboard-layout/

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think this is the solution or that this is enough. I already seen a method to get this keybouard layout **int**, but I need some kind of a string. Since Sogou is a third party IME, I can't see a way to check whether it's used or not with an int. That would require every third-party IMEs to have a unique int value in Windows. So this must be something different.